# RegEx with Google Sheets, Matching Items With Delimiter

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, textjoin

Starting with this

```
za%3A0%2Cca%3A3-2-1-21-1%2Cus%3Apa%2Cus%3Anj
```

Get this

```
(id:za%3A0),(id:ca%3A3-2-1-21-1),(id:us%3Apa),(id:us%3Anj)
```

`%2C` is the delimiter in the starting string. Not always going to be 4 ids, could be 1 could be 70.

First problem I'm having since I'm new to RegEx is how to "match" all ids (ex. `za%3A0`) based on the delimiter.

Comment: may be you can use ="(" & SUBSTITUTE(A149,"%2C","),(") & ")"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, "(id:"&SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A644, "%2C", "♦"), "♦")&")"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I think you can just use substitute, except if any next further purpose (process)

Answer (score 0):

or shorter:

```
="("&SUBSTITUTE(A1, "%2C", "),(")&")"
```

[image: 0]

---

and array:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A="",,"("&SUBSTITUTE(A1:A, "%2C", "),(")&")"))
```

[image: 0]